# When is a field element in its base field?

Tags: field-theory, prime-numbers, finite-fields, extension-field

Let $q = p^r$ some prime power.

Let $f \in \mathbb{F}_{q^m}$, some field extension of $\mathbb{F}_{q}$. Then, if $f = f^q$, then $x \in \mathbb{F}_q$.

Why is this true? Is it simply because $x$ is a root of the polynomial $x^q - x \in \mathbb{F}_q[x]$ and $\mathbb{F}_q[x]$ consists precisely of the roots of this polynomial?

Comment: Yes, that is one way to prove the result.

Comment: Perhaps you meant $\mathbb{F}_q$ and not $\mathbb{F}_q[x]$ consists of the roots of this polynomial.